# Sharepoint powershell IF condition

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

i have a simple if condition as follows...

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$sitelists =  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{
    if ($web -eq "Search")
    {
      Write-Host "Come in"  
    }
}
```

though the site list returns value "Search" the if condition always fails.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this now but I think you need to compare the Name property?

```
if ($web.Name -eq "Search")
```

Comment: it works. I got confused when I use 'Write-Host ($web)', it gives me the correct value.